# Visual Studio 2015 Remote Development

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

When creating a SharePoint project in Visual Studio on my windows 7 machine I receive this error.

> The required version of sharepoint foundation or sharepoint server is
>   not installed on this system. The target version of SharePoint project
>   is 15.0.

I've done some reading and learnt that I can make this work on a remote machine. **My question is, will using Visual Studio on a remote machine result in reduced functionality, what functions would be lost?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any server-side code development (via .NET/C#/VB) using the Microsoft.SharePoint objects is going to give you trouble with Server Side Development if you do not have SharePoint installed.  The great bulk of developers that I've seen setup a separate Dedicated Virtual Machine (using their favorite Hyper-Visor) on the local box if powerful enough, or in a cloud/remote setup if not. The Virtual Machine runs a Server grade OS (Server 2008/2012/2016), installs SharePoint and Visual Studio on the same box and the machine is up and running.

It's a bit troublesome, but it's worth it long term for the grief, and a good learning experience in setting up a SharePoint environment if you're relatively new to SharePoint.

Now if you're only developing Store Apps (basically client-only facing SharePoint Apps) you can get away without the server assemblies, but even then it's nice to have the SharePoint server nearby if you can help it.

Comment: Do you mean setup the SharePoint development environment on their local machine, or on a dedicated virtual host?

Comment: If powerful enough, setup a virtual machine locally on your dev box with a Client Virtual Machine tool like VMWare Player or VMware Workstation.  If not, get a remote virtual machine somewhere and work accordingly.  I edited my question to better clarify.

Comment: Even a SharePoint development environment requires Active Directory and a Domain Controller, does this mean I need to setup an additional AD/DC machine?

Comment: I would recommend setting up a domain or joining an existing one.  Most people box a SharePoint dev machine in its own domain on the same server or join another Developer Domain built for this purpose.  There are a few sneaky tricks to setup a SharePoint machine without Active Directory but it can be tricky.

Comment: Awesome information, can the SharePoint all in one server also be a DC and AD server? I thought this wasn't possible?

Comment: I set them up as Domain Controllers all the time.  It's a really lousy idea in a production environment, but in an isolated Dev environment I consider it "Acceptable" to do so.  Lots of people do seperate "Dev" Domains and link up the SharePoint Dev server(s) there with a seperate domain controller.  Your budget may vary for this.